# How to generate customer Pooling layer prototxt in pycaffe?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

My goal is to achieve a pooling layer prototxt from code as follows:

```
layer {
  name: "my_pooling"
  type: "Pooling_Custom"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "my_pooling"
  pooling_custom_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
    engine : CAFFE
  }
}
```

where `Pooking_Custom` and `pooling_custom_param` are my modify Pooling. I want to use python to generate above output. I am using NetSpec to do it:

```
from caffe import params as P
n = caffe.NetSpec()
my_pooling = L.Pooling(conv1, type="Pooling_Custom",  pool=P.Pooling.MAX, kernel_size=2, stride=2, engine=1)
```

However, I cannot generate `pooling_custom_param`. How can I do it? My current result is

```
layer {
  name: "my_pooling"
  type: "Pooling_Custom"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "my_pooling"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
    engine : CAFFE
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this as a subtype of **Pooling**, you can't: those attribute names are defined by the parent template.  All you can change are the values (right side of each item, after the colon).

The functional reason is that you're incorporating methods from the parent class in which those field names are hard-coded.  For instance, there will be something that refers to **pooling_param["kernel_size"]**.  If you have changed the name to **pooling_custom_param**, you need to also reconfigure that software ... and that's outside the language's software implementation.

If you *really* need to change that attribute name, you're welcome to clone the entire Pooling class, make the change, and instantiate layers of that new class.

Comment: Thanks Prune. Actually, I am using a modified version of Caffe. In the version, I used `pooling_custom_param` to define the pooling parameter. My caffe version worked with my setting using `pooling_custom_param`. In my question, I am focusing on generating the prototxt from the python script, using  `caffe.NetSpec()`. Is it impossible?

Comment: I don't know -- "a modified version of Caffe" doesn't tell me *how* it's modified.  Obviously, you have a hand-altered version that works.  If **NetSpec** isn't similarly modified, I don't think you can generate the label you want; you'd have to add functionality to **NetSpec** to handle that alteration.